# imports fail in subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a Python project, that uses some code from a Github repo. I added the repo using `git submodule add`. So now I have the following file-structure:

```
ProjectFolder\
    foo.py
    BarProject\ (the Github repo added with submodule)
        bar.py
        baz.py
```

In my main file `foo.py` I want to import the method `bar` from the file `bar.py`:

```
from BarProject.bar import bar
```

This fails, because the first line of `bar.py` is :

```
from baz import *
```

And Python throws an `ImportError`, because it cannot find the module baz.

---

Is there a way to import the file `bar.py` in a way, so that the relative imports don't get screwed up? I don't really want to modify `bar.py` or `baz.py`, because they are part of an external Github project.

Comment: try `from .baz import *`

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I don't really want to change the file `bar.py`, because it's part of an Github project that I don't own.

Comment: If it works for you, you can then issue a pull request ;)

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yeah, it works. Maybe I should make a pull request. It's definitely a clean way.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger One more question. Using `from .baz import *` I now can import the `BarProject.bar` without problems. But only executing `bar.py` fails now.

Comment: executing from which folder? `BarProject`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yes.

Comment: So the `BarProject` is supposed to be run on its own and you want to include it as a package? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

remember to add `__init__.py` to `BarProject` folder to indicate that folder is a package.